# how to calculate mean on timestamp using python

Tags: python, timestamp, mean, using

I'm facing error while trying calculate mean on `Datetimestamp` using Pandas.
I tried doing `mean()` in python pandas

```
DB= create_engine('mssql://user/pwd/123)
output=pandas.read_sql(select x,y,timestamp from table)
df = pd.Dataframe(output)
mean=df.groupby(['x','y'])['timestamp'].mean()
mean
```

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I would like to see average of all those timestamps in datetime or time format.

Comment: You're missing an apostrophe in `create_engine('mssql://user/pwd/123)`

Comment: could you add some example input and expected output values? I don't completely understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ID1 ID2 StartTime
342 30854 5/1/19 4:07 AM
342 30854 5/1/19 4:07 AM
342 30854 5/1/19 5:08 AM
342 30854 5/1/19 6:54 AM
342 30854 5/1/19 9:10 AM
342 30854 5/1/19 11:04 AM
342 30854 5/1/19 12:54 PM
342 30854 5/1/19 2:51 PM
342 30854 5/1/19 5:04 PM

Comment: This is the sample dataset , I'm basically looking to find mean on the timestamp. this can be with the date or without date. either way should work for me. Thanks again.

Comment: The average of these timestamps is- 5/1/19 9:29 AM. Basically, I want to be able to achieve that using python. Thanks for your help @drxl

Comment: Any help on this much appreciated.